# Fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, fetch-api

I want to update my HTML page at certain intervals, retrieving data from my Express API.

However, I struggle with integrating any such function into Pug. Both fetch and XMLHttpRequest produce the same error:

> ERROR: "fetch is not a function"

I tried to put the function into an external JavaScript file - same issue.

```
body
 p Welcome
 -
  function httpGet(theUrl)
   { 
    fetch(theUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
    })
   }

p= httpGet('http://localhost:3000/test')
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to call `fetch` server-side. Are you sure you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 'fetch' is not availaible in all browser. You should use a polyfill like
https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: I think this misses the problem OP is having issues with. The code OP has shown above does not run in a browser, in general, but server-side as M90 has commented.

Comment: If he wants to update its html at certain interval of time it must be client side. Otherwise it is would reload the all page, not part of it. So it is a fetch from client side

Comment: I understand fetch must be client side. OP has incorrectly put the fetch code server side (the code in `-` is rendered by the server); suggesting to just use a polyfill will not correct the problem.